# hdd shows in lsusb, but not lsblk

Tags: hard-drive

Long time lurker here.  I have been trying to format a relatively new external hdd, but haven't been successful.  I've tried looking through the forums for answers, but haven't found anything that works.  I'm currently running xubuntu 12.04.

When I plug my external hdd in and out, I can see the device with `lsusb`

When I run `lsblk`, there is no difference between plugging the device in or not.  If I do this with a flash drive, I can see the flash drive associated with /dev/sdx

I ran a second hdd with the same cable, and it worked fine.  I've also tried plugging the device into a Windows machine.  I can see it in device manager, but it does not show up in "my computer".

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Probably corrupted file system. Download [EaseUS Data Recovery Wizard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EaseUS_Data_Recovery_Wizard) application in windows system and try to diagnose the drive. If you are able to see the drive in the wizard,  you can select full recover  to get it back to normal. And you should be able to perform normal operations on it.

I had same kind of problem with my hard drive and this helped , may be this will help you too.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!  Do you think there's any solution that doesn't involve downloading an application?  To get Windows, I'd have to borrow my in-laws' computer and would like to avoid downloading anything if I can.

Comment: were you able to find the drive in gparted partition editor in linux? if yes, you can use it to create new partition tables (assuming that you know about partitions) that can solve your issue. If not,  contact the manufacturer for troubleshooting guide